# javascript - querySelectorAll hover works in jsFiddle but not locally

Tags: javascript, pseudo-class, selectors-api

I would like to output the number of mouse-pointed elements:

```
<p>some text here</p>
<span>number of hovered elements: </span><span id="debugElement"></span>
<script>
    var debugElement = document.getElementById("debugElement");
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => debugElement.innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll(":hover").length);
</script>
```

The code above works as expected on JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/n4vreycp/1/

But not when executed locally.

Comment: Are you sure you're not just looking for `event.currentTarget`?

Comment: Your code works for me, also remember using css :hover selector will propably always return body or html too , alongside your desired hovered element.

Comment: Does the console show some error? Are you sure the script runs after the elements have been loaded? See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/1529630)